# Sqlalchemy returns different results of the SELECT command (query.all)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, sqlalchemy, uwsgi

I have web server (512 RAM) with: 
FLASK + SQLAlchemy (SQLite) -> uWSGI -> Nginx

PROBLEM: Sqlalchemy returns different results of the SELECT command (query.all).

Example:

- Added a few records in the database.
- I reload the page: new records have not returned (but old returned).
- Reload the page: all the records returned. Excellent.
- Reload the page: again new records have not returned. (But old returned).

This happens as long as I do not restart Flask app.

The code below:

```
DECLARATIVE_BASE = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Order(DECLARATIVE_BASE):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    __table_args__ = (
        {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'sqlite_autoincrement': True, 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}
    )

    id = Column(INTEGER, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    name = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    address = Column(TEXT)
    phone = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    email = Column(TEXT)
    comment = Column(TEXT)
    totalPrice = Column(DECIMAL(asdecimal=False))
    orderItems = relationship(Orderitem)
    time = Column(TEXT, default=time.strftime("%H:%m %d.%m.%y"))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Order(%s)>" % self.__dict__

@app.route('/api/orders', methods=['GET'])
def getAllOrders():
    allOrders = session.query(Order).all()
    return json.dumps(allOrders, cls=new_alchemy_encoder(False, ['orderItems', 'product']), check_circular=False, ensure_ascii=False) #ensure_ascii=False -- for rigth out cyrlic;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one SQLAlchemy session per Worker and probably use 2 Workers with uwsgi. SQLAlchemy caches results per session, so session of worker 1 returns the new results, because you have added the records with this worker, but the session of worker 2 is not updated and returns only the old records.

Solution: don't create global sessions, but a new session for each request.

```
@app.route('/api/orders', methods=['GET'])
def getAllOrders():
    session = Session()
    allOrders = session.query(Order).all()
    return json.dumps(allOrders, cls=new_alchemy_encoder(False, ['orderItems', 'product']), check_circular=False, ensure_ascii=False) #ensure_ascii=False -- for rigth out cyrlic;
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right!
The problem of multi-threading and multiprotsessinge uWSGI.
Now I chose a bad way: disabled multithreading and multiprotsessing. But now SQLAlchemy works correctly.
I'll work on it.

Comment: @МаксимДанилов: simply create a new session for **each** request

Comment: SQLA does not cache results of queries, but does use the identity map to return the same object within a session when it encounters the same row. Usually cases of "query does not return inserted" stem from transaction isolation, when reusing a (global) session and its ongoing transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This should help. SQLAlchemy session is not closing correctly!

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    Session.remove()
```